# How to set a custom port for a mysql connection in databases.yml?

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I have a mysql server on localhost:3366, but I can't get Doctrine to connect to it, no matter how I configure it, it still uses the default mysql port which is not what I want.

This is how my databases.yml looks like:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
       dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;port=3366;dbname=mydb
       port: 3366
       username: myuser
       password: mypass
```

I specified the port two times, still it insist on using the default mysql port. How can I get this to work?

Comment: are you sure it's using tcp? "Normally" mysql tries to use local sockets, when it connects to host 'localhost'. Try setting `host=127.0.0.1` and see, if it's any good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well the solution is using: 127.0.0.1, for some reason PDO ignores the port if I use localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but can you try `host=localhost:3366` ?